# Exception with start Nimbus

Tags: ubuntu, apache-storm, nimbus

My target is install and run Storm in localhost Ubuntu.

I use manual:
http://storm.praveendeshmane.co.in/storm/storm-0-10-0-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04.jsp

I try to call:

```
./bin/storm nimbus
```

And see the next:

```
ivan@ivan-workstation /usr/local/storm $ ./bin/storm nimbus
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__908.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12278.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: expected '<document start>', but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 24, column 1:
    storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/sto ... 
    ^

    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:366)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:467)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:177)
    ... 39 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__908.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12278.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: expected '<document start>', but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 24, column 1:
    storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/sto ... 
    ^

    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:366)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:467)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:177)
    ... 39 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__908.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12278.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: expected '<document start>', but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 24, column 1:
    storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/sto ... 
    ^

    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:366)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:467)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:177)
    ... 39 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
    at org.apache.storm.config$fn__908.invoke(config.clj:100)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.config__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5753)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:634)
    at clojure.core$use.doInvoke(core.clj:5843)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value$loading__5340__auto____12278.invoke(config_value.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.command.config_value.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: expected '<document start>', but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 24, column 1:
    storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/sto ... 
    ^

    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:366)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:467)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:177)
    ... 39 more
Running: java -server -Ddaemon.name=nimbus -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/local/storm -Dstorm.log.dir= -Djava.library.path= -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/local/storm/lib/kryo-3.0.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/disruptor-3.3.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/clojure-1.7.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/ring-cors-0.1.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/objenesis-2.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/storm-core-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/asm-5.0.3.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/log4j-core-2.8.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/minlog-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.8.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/storm-rename-hack-1.1.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/reflectasm-1.10.1.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/log4j-api-2.8.2.jar:/usr/local/storm/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/local/storm/conf -Dlogfile.name=nimbus.log -DLog4jContextSelector=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncLoggerContextSelector -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/usr/local/storm/cluster.xml org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus
ERROR StatusLogger File not found in file system or classpath: /usr/local/storm/cluster.xml
ERROR StatusLogger Reconfiguration failed: No configuration found for 'AsyncContext@4b67cf4d' at 'null' in 'null'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.storm.config$read_storm_config.invoke(config.clj:78)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.ui.core__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:5671)
    at clojure.core$load_lib$fn__5397.invoke(core.clj:5711)
    at clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:5710)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:5749)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:632)
    at clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:5832)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus$loading__5340__auto____8195.invoke(nimbus.clj:16)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2154)
    at clojure.lang.RT.classForName(RT.java:2163)
    at clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:2182)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:436)
    at clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:412)
    at clojure.core$load$fn__5448.invoke(core.clj:5866)
    at clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:5865)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
    at clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:379)
    at org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: expected '<document start>', but found BlockMappingStart
 in 'reader', line 24, column 1:
    storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/sto ... 
    ^

    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl$ParseDocumentStart.produce(ParserImpl.java:225)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.peekEvent(ParserImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserImpl.checkEvent(ParserImpl.java:143)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.composer.Composer.getSingleNode(Composer.java:108)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.BaseConstructor.getSingleData(BaseConstructor.java:120)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.loadFromReader(Yaml.java:481)
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.load(Yaml.java:424)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.findAndReadConfigFile(Utils.java:366)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.readStormConfig(Utils.java:467)
    at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:177)
    ... 38 more
ivan@ivan-workstation /usr/local/storm $
```

**Edit**

storm.yaml config file:

```
########### These MUST be filled in for a storm configuration
 storm.zookeeper.servers: "localhost"
#     - "server1"
#     - "server2"
# 
# nimbus.seeds: ["host1", "host2", "host3"]
# 
storm.local.dir: "/usr/local/storm/data"
nimbus.host: "localhost"
nimbus.thrift.port: 49627
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
supervisor.slots.ports:
- 6700
- 6701
- 6702
- 6703
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely looks like something wrong in your `storm.yaml`. Could you post it?

**Update:**

Your second line seems to be the issue

```
 storm.zookeeper.servers: "localhost"
```

(Notice the whitespace in the beginning of the line)

should become:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers: ["localhost"]
```

or

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
  - "localhost"
```

Comment: I added content of storm.yaml in first post.

Comment: thank you. My fix for this problem: to use docker system https://hub.docker.com/_/storm/